# Android Not Showing Font Icon In NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to use Ionicons with Android and NativeScript. I've included the `ionicon.ttf` file and my set `font-family: "Ionicons"`. It's working on iOS, but not Android.

Answer (score 5):

Android registers font names differently than iOS. For Ionicons, the font name is `ionicons.ttf`, so the correct CSS is `font-family: "Ionicons", ionicons`.

Comment: Do you have to get another .ttf to put in the app/fonts folder?